# Jenkins: Trigger related builds in a specific order when any of them are triggered by SCM

Tags: build, jenkins, hudson, integration, polling

Say I have three jobs, A, B and C. They all run integration tests that interact with each other. C is dependent on B, B is dependent on A.

Is there a way to trigger A, then B, then C in that order when an SCM poll triggers any of the three projects?

E.g. I check code into A, and a few minutes later I check code into C. I need A to be built first, then build B to run integration tests, then build C. But I can't guarantee this with conventional polling intervals.

I've looked at the parametrized build plugin but I can't figure out a way to do it without an infinite loop of builds.

Edit: The answer below seems to be the best option BUT I'm using Mercurial and can't find a way to check out multiple Mercurial repos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Granted this is a stale question, but I have an alternative you can use if you're still dealing with this (or someone else runs across this like I did in a search for a similar issue):

- Job A1 - polls repo A but does not sync, triggers Job A2
- Job B1 - polls repo B but does not sync, triggers Job A2
- Job C1 - polls repo C but does not sync, triggers Job A2
- Job A2 - current Job A, triggers Job B2
- Job B2 - current Job B, triggers Job C2
- Job C2 - current Job C

The "does not sync" probably isn't necessary (it'll just sync again on the related job), but would preserve the exact functionality of your current chain.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to configure Job A to always trigger Job B, and Job B to always trigger job C. This will ensure that they run in the order that you need.

Now, you want SCM changes to either of the 3 jobs to start the chain. In Job A, you can do SCM checkouts for all 3 repository location (just don't utilize them in Job A).

This way, the polling will apply to all 3 location, will trigger Job A which in turn triggers the proper chain that you want

Comment: This would be ideal, but I'm using the Mercurial plugin and I can't find a way to poll multiple repos.

Comment: Ahh, found the 'Multiple SCMs' plugin. It's a proof of concept but seems to do the job perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Well, I thought it was working but there seems to be a critical bug in Multiple SCMs that means... you can't check out multiple mercurial repos (the plugin gets confused between revision numbers). I'm gonna leave this answered because it seems like the best way to do it, just there's not a suitable plugin for mercurial yet. If you have any suggestions let me know

Comment: Hmm, never used Mercurial, and SVN allows to simply add multiple checkout locations. If re-organizing the SCM is an option, you can make it so that all 3 locations are under 1 parent location, and then checkout that parent location only